# Who is the first to give the proof of insolvability of quintic functions using Galois theory?

Tags: mathematicians, galois-theory

The first correct proof of the insolvability of the quintic is due to Abel. But my question   is who gave the proof of insolvability of the quintic using Galois theory? Does Abel know about Galois theory?

Comment: A quick skim of Wikipedia reveals, "in 1885, John Stuart Glashan, George Paxton Young and Carl Runge provided a proof using this theory [Galois theory]."

Comment: What do you call "Galois theory"? I think Ruffini's proof used elements of permutation theory. Galois's proof certainly used permutations, and even permutation groups and concepts like normal subgroups. Or do you want a proof explicitly using the concept of an automorphism of a field?